# chartSeries - how to make the plot x label as original date in dataframe

Tags: r, quantmod

When I use  quantmod::chartSeries to draw chart ,how to make the plot x label format as original in data.frame ? Thank!
Below code ,the chart x label is not correce

```
test_data <- data.frame(mydate=as.Date(c('2013-1-1','2023-1-6','2023-1-20')),
                       open = c(1,7,8),
                       high=c(7,10,9),
                       low= c(1,3,4),
                       close=c(1.5,6,7.5))

quantmod::chartSeries(ts(test_data))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(quantmod)
library(xts)

# Create the data.frame
test_data <- data.frame(mydate = as.Date(c('2013-1-1', '2023-1-6', '2023-1-20')),
                        open = c(1, 7, 8),
                        high = c(7, 10, 9),
                        low = c(1, 3, 4),
                        close = c(1.5, 6, 7.5))

# Convert the data.frame to an xts object
test_xts <- xts(test_data[, -1], order.by = test_data$mydate)

# Plot the chart
chartSeries(test_xts, name = "Test Chart")
```